# Integrate liferay cms into existing java application

Tags: content-management-system, liferay, integration

I have an existing java web application, servlet based. I plan to add a module to show news articles to visitors. So i choose liferay as our CMS. The solution in my mind is that using an iframe in my web site to show news articles managed by liferay CMS. If i do so, is it convenient for our news editor to manage news articles with liferay CMS? Shall he/she switched to liferay to do this? It seems that the preview function of liferay CMS could guarantee only the inline iframe's visual effect is nice, am i right here?

Besides, could you please advise me a better solution other than iframe based solution?

I am looking forward for your comments, any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better that liferay includes the existing Web app.

Comment: Our existing web app is based on servlet, the migration is almost impossible due to its high cost.

Comment: From your app you can call Liferay json web services by javascript. https://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JSON+Web+Services